# How to convert the data to json format using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am fetching a data from model using eloquent using `User::find(1);`

How can i convert this to json in laravel method

Is there any way to get it from laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `toJson` method

So you will be adding `return User::find(1)->toJson();` to your code.

Read more about `toJson` [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json)

**Update :**

If you need to get the result as array format then you should use `toArray`

```
return User::find(1)->toArray();
```